# Can't execute stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-express

I have created a stored procedure and can see it under the stored procedure node, but when trying to execute it doesn't find the procedure.

Under stored procedure node it is called dbo.CopyTable

```
exec CopyTable
```

CopyTable is undefined in red saying it does not exist. Why?

Even if I right-click on the procedure and say script stored procedure as execute to - the code it generates is underlined in red and cant find stored procedure either.

Comment: Are you sure you are executing it on the correct database? What about something like `exec [dbName].dbo.CopyTable`

Comment: exec dbo.CopyTable - doesnt work

Comment: @nadG please see my updated answer. Have you ensured the SPROC is valid? Do you get any errors when you execute it?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the database selected contains the stored procedure `CopyTable`

```
USE YourDatabase
EXEC CopyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dbo` and selecting the right database,

```
USE databaseName
GO

EXEC dbo.CopyTable
GO
```

- [Execute a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are just in the wrong database in the query window, you can specify the database like this:

```
EXEC [yourDBName].dbo.CopyTable
```

Reading on how to [Execute a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx)

Considering your updated question:

> Even if i rightclick on the procedure and say script stored procedure
>   as execute to - the code it generates is underlined in red and cant
>   find stored procedure either.

This could happen if your stored procedure is invalid. Please double-check the validity of the SPROC and ensure the tables it references exist, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your CREATE PROCEDURE. Highlight it, f5 it, and then make sure it runs before you call it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your procedure you've accidentally cut-pasted your script name (dbo.CopyTable), say something like...

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CopyTable
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
RETURN
```

Then when you call your proc you get 'invalid object name dbo.CopyTable' and assume sql is having trouble finding the stored-proc ... which isn't the problem, its finding and running the proc but its actually a problem within the proc.